# Hot to flatten nested array of objects using lodash?

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have a json object that I need to convert in javascript using lodash:

```
{
    "BidNumber": 2,
    "BidResult": 1,
    "BidAmount": "6756",
    "BidData": [
        {
            "name": "JonSnow",
            "Data": "Standard data for Jon Snow"
        },
        {
            "LineNum": "HarryPotter",
            "Data": "Standard data for Jon Snow"
        },
        {
            "LineNum": "MickyMouse",
            "Data": "Standard data for Micky Mouse"
        }
    ],
    "BidReference": "22e06e66-e711-bd14-7874a-002219649f24"
}
```

I want to convert that to:

```
{
    "bidNumber": 2,
    "bidResult": 1,
    "bidAmount": "6756",
    "bidData": {
        "jonSnow": "Standard data for Jon Snow",
        "harryPotter": "Standard data for Jon Snow",
        "mickyMouse": "Standard data for Micky Mouse"
    },
    "bidReference": "22e06e66-e711-bd14-7874a-002219649f24"
}
```

Can't figure it out the way I can do it in lodash (including camelCase part)

Comment: Does it *have* to be with lodash?  This is trivial in vanilla Javascript

Comment: Yes, because that collection is much larger in reality.

Comment: Yes, sorry it should be "Standard data for Harry Potter". Good spot, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be easily done with JS..

```
data.BidData = Object.assign({}, ...data.BidData.map(el => { 
  return { [(el.name ? el.name : el.LineNum)]: el.Data } 
}));
```

You dont need to use loadash unless you want to use `_.extend`

```js
var data = {
    "BidNumber": 2,
    "BidResult": 1,
    "BidAmount": "6756",
    "BidData": [
        {
            "name": "JonSnow",
            "Data": "Standard data for Jon Snow"
        },
        {
            "LineNum": "HarryPotter",
            "Data": "Standard data for Jon Snow"
        },
        {
            "LineNum": "MickyMouse",
            "Data": "Standard data for Micky Mouse"
        }
    ],
    "BidReference": "22e06e66-e711-bd14-7874a-002219649f24"
};

data.BidData = Object.assign({}, ...data.BidData.map(el => { 
  return { [jslcfirst(el.name ? el.name : el.LineNum)]: el.Data } 
}));

console.log(data);

function jslcfirst(string) 
{
    return string.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: @Archer looks fine now!

Comment: That looks really great! Is it possible to lowercase that part within the map() function?

Comment: You don't need the function any more, since the field name is always the same.

Comment: Quick update, we have camelCase only for BidData... how to do it with all keys in that object?

Comment: @Quang `jslcfirst ` this function lowercases the first character keeping all the other characters same. So ideally it solves that. Also as it answers your question please mark the answer correct!

Comment: @void You are correct except that the BidNumber, BidResult, BidAmount should also be camelCased...

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash:

```
obj.BidData = _.reduce(obj.BidData, function(flatObj, item) {
    flatObj[_.camelCase(item.name || item.LineNum)] = item.Data;
    return flatObj;
},{});
```

But you would not necessarily need lodash(underscore), using vanilla JS this is easily achievable

```
function convertToCamelCase(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + string.slice(1);
}

obj.BidData = obj.BidData.reduce(function(flatObj, item) {
    flatObj[convertToCamelCase(item.name || item.LineNum)] = item.Data;
    return flatObj;
},{})
```

Comment: That is truly awesome! Thank you.

Comment: actually I'm getting [ts] error: Property 'LineNum' does not exists on type {}...#

Comment: Which means one of your items on BidData array isn't having either of 'name' or 'LineNum' field